# Offset row function in python?

Tags: python

How do I write a python code for calculating values for a new column --"UEC_saving" by OFFSET # of rows in the "UEC"column. The table format is pandas dataframe.

Positive numbers in the "Offset_rows" column means shift rows down and vice versa.

For example, "UEC_saving" for index 0 is 8.6-7.2 and for index 2 is 0.2-7.0

The output for "UEC_saving" should look like this:

```
    Product_Class UEC  Offset_rows  UEC_saving
0      PC1         8.6     1           1.4
1      PC1         7.2     0           0.0
2      PC1         0.2    -1           -7.0
3      PC2         18.8    2           2.2
4      PC2         10.0    1           1.4
5      PC2         8.6     0           0.0
6      PC2         0.3    -1           -8.3
```

Comment: What format is your data in? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Looks like pandas.

Comment: should index 3 be 18.8 - 8.6 = 10.2?

Comment: @DerekEden: Your're correct. index 3 should be 18.6-8.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i,'UEC_saving'] = row['UEC'] - df.loc[i+row['Offset_rows']]['UEC']

df

    UEC  Offset_rows  UEC_saving
0   8.6            1         1.4
1   7.2            0         0.0
2   0.2           -1        -7.0
3  18.8            2        10.2
4  10.0            1         1.4
5   8.6            0         0.0
6   0.3           -1        -8.3
```

this lines up with all your desired answers except for index 3, please let me know if there was a typo, or please explain further in your question exactly what occurs there